# Possible that one model is better than two?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict `fantasy_points` for individual Basketball players in upcoming games. The formula to calculate a player's `fantasy_points` is:

`fantasy_points = (1 * points_scored) + (1.5 * assists)`

So if Player A scores 10 points and 4 assists:

Player A `fantasy_points` = (1 x 10) + (1.5 x 4) = 16

I have a few seasons worth of player data. My data is organized so that one row represents a player's performance in one game. This includes explanatory variables that are knowable before the game (player age, past performance variables, opponent strength) and the target variables `points_scored`, `assists` and `fantasy_points`.

```
| player | explanatory variables | points_scored | assists      | fantasy_points |
|--------|-----------------------|---------------|--------------|---------------------:|
| A      | ...                   | 10            | 4            |             16 |
| B      | ...                   | 3             | 10           |             18 |
| C      | ...                   | <to predict>  | <to predict> | <to predict>   |
```

Using Scikit-Learn's `ElasticNet` regressor along with `GridSearchCV` to find the best penalty, I tried to predict how many fantasy points players will have in an upcoming game.

I've tried two approaches(training/CV not shown):

**Two Model Approach**: I trained two separate models:

- A `points_scored_model` trained with `points_scored` as it's target
- An `assists_model` trained with `assists` as it's target

To figure out how many `fantasy_points` a player would have in an upcoming game, I combined the predictions like this:

```
predicted_points_scored = points_scored_model.predict(row_for_player_c)
predicted_assists       = assists_model.predict(row_for_player_c)

predicted_fantasy_points = \
  (1 * predicted_points_scored) + (1.5 * predicted_assists)
```

**One Model Approach**: I trained one model:

- `fantasy_points_model` trained with `fantasy_points` as it's target

Then I predicted fantasy points like this:

```
predicted_fantasy_points = fantasy_points_model.predict(row_for_player_c)
```

Because the underlying formula (1*points + 1.5*assists) is incorporated into the **Two Model Approach**, I would imagine that it would be able to predict `fantasy_points` more accurately than the **One Model Approach**.

I used R^2 score to compare the models and it turns out that the **One Model Approach** performs much better than the  **Two Model Approach**.

It seems like the **One Model Approach** has less information about the problem so how could it score better? Additionally, is there a way to leverage the fantasy points formula to get better predictions?

Comment: Where did you get the 1 point and 1.5 points?  What type of regression did you use?  What are total fantasy points?  Are you regressing assists and points scored onto total fantasy points?  How are you deciding on thing is better than another, by what criterion?

Comment: @DaveHarris the 1pt and 1.5pts are not coefficients, 1* points scored + 1.5*assists is how you figure out how many fantasy points a player scored during a game. I used a penalized regression to model points_scored, assists and fantasy_points. I am comparing the 'One Model Approach' and 'Two Model Approach' using r^2.

Comment: I reckon Ben's answer raises the critical issue, there is no reason to believe that the two are independent - in fact intuition would tend to be that  if a player is playing well then they are more likely to score more and assist more. The 1 model scenario explicitly builds this relationship in, so is more accurate. The 2 model situation has no way of knowing how to adjust assists and scores to avoid overcounting. If half of the assist are is explained by the same factors as score, then you count this twice in the assist model and in the score model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a perspective: the two model approach is *more* constrained, hence is always going to result in an inferior model. Consider the 2m (two-model) model - it looks like:

$$ f_{2m}(\mathbf{x}) = 1.5 (\mathbf{c_1} \cdot \mathbf{x}^T) + 1.0 (\mathbf{c_2} \cdot \mathbf{x}^T)$$

where $\mathbf{c}_i$ were trained in separate models. We can rewrite this as a 1m (one-model):

$$ f_{1m}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x}^T $$

such that

$$ \mathbf{c} = 1.5\mathbf{c_1} + 1.0\mathbf{c_2}$$

There's *no reason* to believe that $\mathbf{c}$ is the minimum of the least squares problem

$$ \min_{\mathbf{b}} \; (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{X})^2$$

however, the global 1m model *is* the solution of that minimization problem. In fact, if  you keep using linear models, you'll *never* beat 1m's $R^2$ - it's an upper bound.

In english: yes, you have given the model more information, but that doesn't mean that the solution is optimal. In a system with noise, and the guarantee of model misspecification, I think you'll always do worse than the global model.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So just to re-state your answer as I understand it, there's no reason to believe that minimizing (y-X*b)^2 (target - explanatory variables * coefficients)^2 for two separate target variables (2m)will be any better than trying to solve for some combination of those targets (1m). In fact, because the 1m is minimizing MSE of the target directly, it's solution will be the best possibly linear solution.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like you're implying that 1m's r2 could be improved by using non-linear models. Would you expect the same results of 1m vs. 2m using non-linear models (maybe some kind of tree ensemble)? It seems strange to me that knowing the underlying formula wouldn't give you some kind of predictive advantage. Anyways, I really appreciate your answer and the time you took to write it! cheers

Comment: "In fact, because the 1m is minimizing MSE of the target directly, it's solution will be the best possibly linear solution" - that's correct (and well said). For any other type of model, though the argument isn't as clear, and point still stands that optimizing for the target directly is desirable. But try it and see!

Comment: While it's true that $R^2$ will be minimized by the global model, it's possible that the 2m approach generalizes better. In fact, this is guaranteed if you know that your two dependent variables are independent (of each other) when conditioned on X.

Answer (score 4):

> Impossible that one predictive model is better than two?

Rather than getting into the weeds on your specific models, let's just step back and view this question in a more general setting.  If we consider an arbitrary series of observable values, then it is possible that a model could give a perfect prediction of those values, and it is possible that a model could give terrible predictions.  That is, it is possible for one model to be *right* and the other to be *wrong*.  Now, if we combine these two models by some aggregation method, the only contribution of the second model is to pollute the first model, and introduce error.  Thus, *it is clearly possible for one predictive model to be better than two*.

Now, getting to your actual model, what is happening here is that you have separated your predictions for the `points scored` and `assists` for each player, and then you have aggregated them *post-hoc*.  It is unclear exactly what you have done to predict these.  You say you have used regression for the predictions, but you have not specified any explanatory variables, and it is also unclear if you even have multiple data points for each player.  In any case, by modelling each variable separately, this implicitly treats these two things as if they are statistically independent, when they are probably related.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ben, I'll try to give some more insight to the problem. I have explanatory variables, most are moving averages like lifetime_average_points_scored_per_game, average_time_played_per_game_over_last_10_games, game_win_percentage_this_season. I also have multiple data points per player. I have historical data going back a few seasons which is organized so that each row corresponds to one player's performance in one game. Finally for all of the models, I'm using ScikitLearn's ElasticNet linear regressor along with GridSearchCV to find a good alpha and l1_ratio.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have indicated, simply adding a model that is wrong can decrease performance. However, there are clever ways around this issue.

Generalized stacking algorithms (super learner is one example) is an alternative strategy to aggregating the results of multiple models. It has the advantage of discarding wrong (or poorly performing) models, so that only models with good information are retained. Essentially, it breaks the data into $k$ pieces and fits each model to each slice and predicts in a hold-out set. The results of each model are then regressed to generate weights, with better performing models having a greater weight in the final predictions. Models that don't improve predictions have weights near 0. A large number of different algorithms can be used (it increases run-time though). This open-access paper gives further explanation: [Rose 2013](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/177/5/443/141300)

For a Python implementation, I use [SuPyLearner](https://github.com/alexpkeil1/SuPyLearner) (not on PyPI but you can download from GitHub)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I've looked into generalized stacking algorithms a little bit and they look interesting. It's something I want to eventually look into more.